# Convert epoch to timestamp in HSQLDB on insert statement

Tags: sql, hsqldb

In the docs, I found the function [TIMESTAMPADD](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html).

I'm trying to to this:

```
insert into status(identifier, firstoccurrence) values('foo', 
    timestampadd(SQL_TSI_SECOND, 1389995576, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00'));
```

But I got this error:

> data exception: interval field overflow / Error Code: -3435 / State: 22015

It seems like there is a problem with the epoch value `1389995576`.

The problem is I can't use a bigger time unit, such as day or month, to then divide this constant value because theese are pricise data.

Are there any other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the direct conversion function:

```
insert into status(identifier, firstoccurrence) values('foo', 
    timestamp(1389995576));
```

The TIMESTAMPADD function will be extended in future versions to accept large values